Can some resource in one subnet access azure blob storage using a private endpoint created in another subnet
I have created a private endpoint between a subnet and azure blob storage.
I can access the azure blob storage using resources from within this subnet.
Can this private endpoint be accessed from another subnet resource.

Also will it be a good practice to create seperate subnet for all azure endpoints.

Yes, You can access the Azure Blob Storage through the private endpoint from another subnet within the same virtual network.


Can some resource in one subnet access azure blob storage using a private endpoint created in another subnet

If you have a storage account with a private endpoint in one subnet (Subnet 1) and you are trying to access it from another subnet (Subnet 2) in the same Virtual Network. the traffic between the two subnets will be allowed unless you create any NSG rules that restrict it.
If you have multiple private endpoints, you can create an additional subnet and use it for all the endpoints, but it is not necessary to use the same subnet for all private endpoints.
Reference: Stack link by  Ansuman Bal
